# AngularJS set one field value to another field within the object

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Maybe stupid question but

```
$scope.registration = {
        email: "",
        userName: "",
        password: "",
        confirmPassword: "",
        firstName: "DummyFirstName",
        lastName: "DummyLastName"
    };
```

I want that `userName` is the same as `email`.

I tried like:

```
$scope.registration = {
        email: "",
        userName: email,
        password: "",
        confirmPassword: "",
        firstName: "DummyFirstName",
        lastName: "DummyLastName"
    };
```

but I get error that not exist.

Comment: Just use the same model. Otherwise, use a $watch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do:

```
$scope.registration = {
    email: "",
    password: "",
    confirmPassword: "",
    firstName: "DummyFirstName",
    lastName: "DummyLastName"
};
$scope.registration.userName = $scope.registration.email;
```

Comment: Why even include `userName: ""` then?

Comment: @cst1992 Yes, that would do as well.

Comment: Could be a system that used to allow usernames, but now is just email addresses. Starbucks did that.